# Access denied: no access to call this method. OpenAPI JS?

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

вылезает такая ошибка при запросе API метода, прочитал в документации, что, требуется access_token. Ребята кто-то сможет показать как примерно должен быть код для получение токена и вызова метода?

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/access_token  - гайд где получить токен

Answer (score 0):

В OpenApi токен не нужен, библиотека добавляет его самостоятельно после авторизации.

Скорее всего, вы пытаетесь вызвать какой-то метод, который в принципе недоступен сайтам.